# writing probability function mathematically (in the shape of $f(x)$}...}

Tags: probability-theory, logic, conditional-probability

I am trying to write the following expression mathematically:  let $X_1,X_2$ be independent random variables, each having the probability function $P_X(k)=p(1-p)^k$ for k=0,1,... and $0<p<1$.

Is it something like $\forall X_1X_2 \exists p_X(k)=p(1-p)^k|(k=0,1,2,..) \land (0<p<1)$ ?

I would appreciate a correction and explanation, so I could not repeat the same mistake in the future.

Note:  I did not define what is an independent random variable there; I just gave a general expression for random variables $X_1,X_2$. If you could, I would appreciate seeing how to write it with the definition of independence.

Thank you very much!

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are "fixed"; if so, we cannot quantify them.

Comment: $P_X(k)$ must be (I think) $P_{X_i}(k)$ for $i=1,2$.